# How do I fix NoMethodError when trying to create a pin in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, scaffolding

Excuse me for maybe being naive, this is my first time using StackOverflow and I'm trying to learn ruby. I'm making an application through onemonthrails.com's tutorial that is similar to pinterest. I'm trying to add a pin and I keep getting the error:

NoMethodError in Pins#new

Showing /Users/jake/code/omrails/app/views/pins/_form.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `description' for #
Extracted source (around line #5):

I dont know what all will help you answer the question so I'll post all the files I received (that may be relevant to the question) when I ran the following command:
$ rails generate scaffold Pins

the migration file:

```
class CreatePins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

the model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description
end
```

_form.html.erb: (This is where it found the error)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@pin) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb: (this is "trace of template conclusion")

```
<h1>New pin</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
```

I don't understand the error because I thought the method was defined in the model under attr_accessible :description

I'd appreciate your help if you can understand anything i just said. If not thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: can you show us how you set `@pin` please ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the migrations to create the `pins` table.

```
 rake db:migrate
```

If it complains that the table exists, this means that you ran the migration *before* adding the `description` column.  Rerunning the migration won't work without first reverting it:

```
 rake db:migrate:redo
```

To clarify your point about `attr_accessible :description` - `attr_accessible` does *not* define the attribute for your model.  Your database table does that (usually as per your migrations).  What `attr_accessible` does is act as a whitelist for mass-assignable attributes.

Comment: Yes I already ran rake db:migrate and when I ran it again just now it gave me an error, SQLite3::SQLException: table "pins" already exists: CREATE TABLE "pins"

Comment: @josephreed: You likely ran it before you added the `description` column to the migration, see updated.

Comment: I did. I ran $ rails generate scaffold Pins but then realized the teacher ran $ rails generate scaffold Pins description:string --skip-stylesheets so i did the same to add description and thats where everything went to hell

Comment: when i try to revert it it gives me the exact same error and aborts the migration

Comment: is there a way to delete the scaffold and just start over?

Comment: @josephreed: Run rake db:rollback

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you did not `rake db:migrate` after you created your scaffold. Try that first.

> I don't understand the error because I thought the method was defined
>   in the model under attr_accessible :description

The `attr_accessible :description` declaration doesn't actually define the method. ActiveRecord does that under the hood for you based on the columns in your `pins` table. If you did not run the migration (and therefore create your table) ActiveRecord will not be able to auto generate attribute methods on your model, which could very well cause the error you're seeing.

`attr_accessible` declares your attributes accessible for being set via mass assignment. Typically, when you do this in your controller: `@pin = Pin.new params[:pin]` where `params[:pin]` is a hash of your model's attributes.

Comment: Yes I already ran rake db:migrate and when I ran it again just now it gave me an error, SQLite3::SQLException: table "pins" already exists: CREATE TABLE "pins"

Comment: is there a way to delete the scaffold and just start over?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check you database table "`pins`"  having `description` column? If not, try to drop your previous table and try to create new one with `description` column.

or you can create a migration file to update your existing table, like:

```
rails g migration add_description_to_pins
```

then inside this file:

```
class AddDescriptionToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :pins, :description, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :pins, :description
  end
end
```

Comment: how do I drop my table entirely and start over? I tried adding your file but it didnt work and i still couldnt rake db:migrate

Comment: try `DROP TABLE pins` entering into database console. Why don't you use some database explorer like: phpmyadmin?